# oriendDB how to access linked data

Tags: database, orientdb, graph-databases

I have a class projects extend V a class clients extend V and an edge hasInvites extend E.

projects has attributes name etc.

clients, has attribute clientName etc.

hasInvites has attributes dueDate.

The hasInvites edge the in and out have links to the projects and clients classes.

I can query hasInvites like

```
select * from hasInvites
```

which give me the correct data

```
out: (the project that's linked #35:34 and the client that's linked #36:11)
dueDate:  2017-01-01
```

How can I access the linked data from the projects and clients?

I have tried the expand() function for that does not work.  i.e.:

```
select *, expand(in(projects)) from hasInvites
```

What i want to get is data like this:

```
dueDate: 2017-01-01
projectName: Project A (taken from the projects class)
clientName:  client A (taken from the clients class)
```

In MySQL, I would do a view with a join and access the projectName and the clientName.

How do i access those in orientDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example :

- the 'in' is the Vertex 'project' with the params 'projectName'
- the 'out' is the Vertex 'client' with the params 'clientName'
- the 'link' is the Edge 'hasInvites' with the params 'dueDate'

You can do :

```
SELECT dueDate, in.projectName, out.clientName From hasInvites
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it worked. thank you.  i tried everything but that.  second part of the question.  the vertex has a few more attributes.  is there any way to embed the object from the Vertex 'in' (not just the projectName.  i know i can do in.att1, in.att2 etc but i want to embed it as an object ).